# Gmail send as alias

Tags: gmail

I was using gamil to receive emails from my own domain and send emails via gmail from my domain as an example info@mydomain.com

All appeared to be working fine up to the first of June. In gmail I could receive emails from info@mydomain.com and send emails via gmail as info@mydomain.com

I can still receive emails from info@mydomain.com but I am now unable to send emails as info@mydomain.com alias.

I have nuked my alias info@mydomain.com from `Settings > accounts and imports > send mail as`

I have attempted to re add my alias info@mydomain.com `Settings > accounts and imports > send mail as > add another email address`

When I now get to `Send Verification`, the verification is never received by info@mydomain.com (I have checked, spam etc.

The dialog rather than proceeding to the verification page bounces back to `Configure your emails to be sent through mydomain.com SMTP servers Learn more`

I also tried to go to my `google account > singing in with google > app passwords` to create SMTP but I do not have the option `app passwords`

Any help would be great